# Is there a flipped `(.)`?

Tags: haskell

The standard library provides many flipped versions of standard operators. `>>=` has `=<<`, `$` has `&`, etc.. Does `.` have a flipped version? I would really rather not have to define one myself, if it already exists.

Comment: Yes, [`Control.Category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Category.html) defines `(<<<) = (.)` and `(>>>) = flip (<<<)` for left-to-right "diagrammatic order".